# How to get Aquamacs to run code in ipython

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, aquamacs, python-mode

I am using Aquamacs on OS X lion and trying to use the latest python-mode.el to edit and run my python code. I can get the ipython shell to open by typing C-!, but if I run either C-c 
C-c or C-c | the python code runs in a new *Python* buffer without ipython.  I have tried a number of fixes. Here are the python specific parts of my .emacs file:

```
(when (featurep 'python) (unload-feature 'python t))
;; add custom libs
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/tools/emacs")
;; Set up pylab 
(setq py-install-directory "/Users/stringham/tools/emacs/")
(require 'python-mode)
(setq py-shell-name "/usr/local/bin/ipython")
(setq py-python-command "/usr/local/bin/ipython")
```

Has anyone had success in using ipython with Aquamacs?

Answer (score 0):

Shebang will precede default-setting.
To override shebang use for example M-x `py-execute-buffer-ipython` RET

Committed a fix. Please check out current trunk at

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Either via bazaar:

```
bzr branch lp:python-mode
```

or downloading from your browser.